# How can you configure ReSharper to make a build fail if code convention rules are violated?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, resharper

Using VS2015 update 2, ReSharper 2016.1, is there a way to configure ReSharper to make a build fail if code convention rules are violated?

Comment: I don't see how this question is too broad, but anyways.... Configure all the convention rules (namely inspections) to _error_ level, and the build will fail.

Comment: For me, even after changing level to error, I am seeing build as Succeeded.