# C# Build should fail; if is there any C# code quality error shown by Re-sharper

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, resharper, static-code-analysis

After changing Code Inspection setting to error for one the C# rule (Empty catch block) to error. In VS2015 I can see error and once I Rebuild/Build my project. Re-sharper won't fail the build.

Could you please, tell me know how to configure re-sharper. So that if is there any C# code quality error. Re-sharper should fail the build.

Comment: Well, duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37609902/how-can-you-configure-resharper-to-make-a-build-fail-if-code-convention-rules-ar) but no answers

Comment: Not implemented, but requested: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-78625

Comment: I don't know why people are not responding to this question. This issue doesn't seems to be too new. Only thing is I am very new to Re-Sharper.